# Why are my integration tests are running when I run my unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, integration-testing

I have spring, spring MVC and gradle based web application. I have configured unit as well as integration tests in the app.

When I run the gradle test, it also runs my integration test. I am not sure why.

I have kept my integration test in separate source folder.

My unit tests are in src/test/java and integration tests are in src/integTest/java.

Below is my build.gradle

```
check.dependsOn integrationTest

tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}



sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integTest/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integTest/resources')
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs the integration tests."
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

    testLogging {
        events "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Comment: why the downvote? Any comment will be helpful to improve the question or if anything is missing.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems here. If you run `gradle test --info` it may tell you why it's running the integrationTest task. If not obvious from that, perhaps you can try using a task tree plugin https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree and see if there's an unexpected task dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove `check.dependsOn integrationTest`

Comment: Can you give a small explanation why he has to remove this line?